# Can we de-decohere an open system?

Tags: density-matrix, decoherence

Can a mixed state become pure due to its interaction with a vast environment? Certainly, a strange proposal, and yet let's take a diagonal matrix representing a mixed state, say $$\begin{pmatrix}
p_{1} & \cdots  & 0 \cr
\vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots  \cr
0 & \cdots  & p_{n}
\end{pmatrix}$$
And study its interaction with a large environment through the Lindblad equation. Let's set the system's Hamiltonian to zero for simplicity and take the Lindblad operators  $L_{i}$ to be $\alpha\left|\psi_{k}\middle>\middle<\psi_{i}\right|$, allowing transitions to the k-th state to occur. Then the matrix would get closer and closer to a pure state matrix $diag(0,\cdots , 1,\cdots ,0)$ with a one on the k-th row.

Does this make any sense? Could this be implemented physically? And if so, what could the Hamiltonian of such an interaction look like? Ty!

Answer (score 1):

A basic example of this is [Amplitude Damping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude_damping_channel), where states decay into $|0\rangle$.

However, we would still consider this a type of decoherence, since regardless of the initial state, the final state is always the same so information about the input is being lost.